# Getting a bitmap of a spark window

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, air, flex4

I have an AIR application that I'm working on in which I would like to basically get a bitmap of what's going on in a separate spark window.  The use case is a scaled preview of the spark window that will likely be on a projector to the main display.  I want to pump the bitmap into a spark image as a source.  Googling this doesn't seem to reveal much or I just don't what terms to google.  Can anybody point me in the right direction?  Anybody have a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to make screenshot of Window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to make a bitmap of some DisplayObject, be it the whole window (stage) or just a Sprite, you should use the BitmapData's draw() method.

The following code will take a "screen shoot" of the whole stage, make a bitmap image of it and add it scaled to the top left corner:

```
var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
bd.draw(stage);

var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bd);
bitmap.width = 300;
bitmap.scaleY = bitmap.scaleX;
addChild(bitmap);
```

It would benefit you to read more on Bitmap and BitmapData to utilize such features as:

- Pixel snapping
- Smoothing
- Transparency

and others. For example smoothing is something that would make the image look better when scaled, but it counts as a filter and can be a performance hitter. That's why it would be better to apply smoothing on the bitmapdata when drawing (drawing scaled image is done with the matrix), not on a bitmap; but only when you don't plan to scale the image during runtime.

Hope that answers your question!